# Highcharts not rendering to JQuery generated div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, highcharts

I'm generating a chart via Highcharts on a jquery created div. However, the chart doesn't seem to be created. Below is the code I use

```
var topRow = jQuery('<tr></tr>', {class: "with-sub"});
                var td = jQuery('<td></td>', {colspan: $scope.statuses.length + 3});
                var subwrap = jQuery('<div></div>', {class: "sub-wrap"});

var chartsParent = jQuery('<div></div>', {class: "L chart"});

subwrap.append(chartsParent);

td.append(subwrap);
                topRow.append(td);
                topRow.insertAfter( jQuery("tbody tr") );

new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        renderTo: chartsParent[0]
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    series: [{
                        data: [
                            ['Firefox',   44.2],
                            ['IE7',       26.6],
                            ['IE6',       20],
                            ['Chrome',    3.1],
                            ['Other',    5.4]
                        ]
                    }]
                });
```

I've also tried rendering to an existing DOM element, however, when I appended it to the div element, the data was lost.

I've searched quite a lot but I can't seem to make it work. Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Adding the whole method body

```
 // Will generate the main table rows that are clickable.
        $scope.getUserStatusDetails = function(request) {
            listByStatusService.getUserStatusDetails(request).then(function(response) {
                jQuery.each(response, function(ind, obj) {
                    var tableRow = jQuery('<tr></tr>', {id: "u" + ind, onclick: "angular.element(this).scope().getSpecifics('u" + ind + "', " + obj.userid + ")"});
                    tableRow.append("<td class='col-1'>" + obj.firstname + " " + obj.lastname + "</td>");
                    tableRow.append("<td class='col-2'>" + obj.department + "</td>");
                    tableRow.append("<td class='col-3'>" + obj.role + "</td>");
                    jQuery.each($scope.statuses, function(ind, status) {
                        tableRow.append("<td class='col-3'>" + Math.round(obj.statusValues[status.name]) + " mins</td>");
                    });
                    jQuery("tbody").append($compile(tableRow)($scope));
                });
            });
        }

    // Will Get the data and call buildSpecificDetails to generate the row.
    $scope.getSpecifics = function(rowid, userid) {
        // Remove the row if it exists.
        if (jQuery('tbody tr#spec_' + rowid).length > 0) {
            jQuery("tbody tr#spec_" + rowid).remove();
        } else {
            var promises = [];
            promises.push(listByStatusService.getUserStatuses($scope.dateFrom.valueOf(), $scope.dateTo.valueOf(), userid).then(function(response) {return response}));
            promises.push(listByStatusService.getUserTasks($scope.dateFrom.valueOf(), $scope.dateTo.valueOf(), userid).then(function(response) {return response}));
            Promise.all(promises).then(function(response) {
                $scope.buildSpecificDetails(rowid, response[0], response[1]); // Add Tasks later
            });
        }
    }

    // Will append a row under the tr that was clicked.
    $scope.buildSpecificDetails = function(rowid, statuses, tasks) {
            var topRow = jQuery('<tr></tr>', {id: "spec_" + rowid, class: "with-sub"});
            var td = jQuery('<td></td>', {colspan: $scope.statuses.length + 3});
            var subwrap = jQuery('<div></div>', {class: "sub-wrap"});

            // TASKS AND IDLE
            var tasksAndIdle = jQuery('<div></div>', {class: "L"});
            tasksAndIdle.append('<h4>Tasks Done</h4>');
            var tasksTable = jQuery('<table></table>', {class: "table table-striped table-condensed table-sub"});
            var tasksTableBody = jQuery('<tbody></tbody>');
            jQuery.each(tasks, function(key, value) {
                    var taskRow = jQuery('<tr></tr>');
                    taskRow.append('<td class="col-1">' + key + '</td>');
                    taskRow.append('<td class="col-2">' + Math.round(value) + ' mins</td>');
                    tasksTableBody.append(taskRow);
            });
            tasksTable.append(tasksTableBody);
            tasksAndIdle.append(tasksTable);
            tasksAndIdle.append('<br/>')
            tasksAndIdle.append('<h4>Idle</h4>');
            var idleTable = jQuery('<table></table>', {class: "table table-striped table-condensed table-sub"});
            var idleTbody = jQuery('<tbody></tbody');
            var idleTrow = jQuery('<tr></tr>');
            idleTrow.append('<td class="col-1">Idle</td>');
            if (statuses['Idle'] != null) {
                idleTrow.append('<td class="col-2">' + Math.round(statuses['Idle']) + ' mins</td>');
            }
            idleTbody.append(idleTrow);
            idleTable.append(idleTbody);
            tasksAndIdle.append(idleTable);
            subwrap.append(tasksAndIdle);
            // TASKS AND IDLE

            // AUX REASONS
            var auxReasons = jQuery('<div></div>', {class: "L"});
            var auxTable = jQuery('<table></table>', {class: "table table-striped table-condensed table-sub"});
            var auxTableBody = jQuery('<tbody></tbody>');
            jQuery.each(statuses, function(key, value) {
                if (key != "Active" && key != "Idle" && key != "Working") {
                    var auxRow = jQuery('<tr></tr>');
                    auxRow.append('<td class="col-1">' + key + '</td>');
                    auxRow.append('<td class="col-2">' + Math.round(value) + ' mins</td>');
                    auxTableBody.append(auxRow);
                }
            });
            auxTable.append(auxTableBody);
            auxReasons.append('<h4>Top Aux Reasons</h4>');
            auxReasons.append(auxTable);
            subwrap.append(auxReasons);
            // AUX REASONS

            // CHART
            var chartsParent = jQuery('<div></div>', {class: "L chart"});
            //var chartsDiv = jQuery('<div></div>', {id: "indiv-summary-" + rowid});
            //chartsParent.append(chartsDiv);
            subwrap.append(chartsParent);
            // CHART

            td.append(subwrap);
            topRow.append(td);
            topRow.insertAfter( jQuery("tbody tr#" + rowid) );

            new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    renderTo: chartsParent[0]
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    data: [
                        ['Firefox',   44.2],
                        ['IE7',       26.6],
                        ['IE6',       20],
                        ['Chrome',    3.1],
                        ['Other',    5.4]
                    ]
                }]
            });

    }
```

Everything else works as expected except for the part where the chart should be created. Thanks in advance

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854106/i-am-using-highcharts-with-bootstrap might be helpful.

Comment: `renderTo: jQuery(document).find('div.chart')`. Try this

Comment: Does the table you want to add your chart to even exist? I created such and chart is appended without problems. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zzccy366/.

Comment: @d_paul It does. When I check the DOM, I can see that the chartsParent element has been created and exists in the DOM. But, the div is empty.

Comment: @paaaaat Could you provide us with the demo where this occurs?

Comment: @d_paul I can't really add more as it involves some server side fetching of data. But what I can explain is that the "tbody tr" is actually "tbody tr#"... with the id of another generated tr. Let's say I'm generating a tr with id u0, u1, u2...un. What I'm really trying to do is to create another tr which contains more data (this will have the chart) under the tr whose id is dynamic. I can tell that the table and tr exists because all other data that I generate dynamically displays properly. It's just the chart that's missing.